# useMatches handle is undefined on sub-routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React router v6 and `createBrowserRouter` to accomplish generating breadcrumbs data using route `handle`.

Partial router code:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: "/app",
    children: [
      {
        element: <RequireUserAuth />,
        children: [
          {
            element: <Layout />,
            children: [
              {
                index: true,
                element: <Dashboard />,
                handle: {
                  crumb: { text: "some crumb text", capitalize: false },
                },
              },
              {
                path: ":project",
                element: <RequireProjectParameter />,
                children: [
                  {
                    index: true,
                    element: <ProjectGeneral />,
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

**The problem**:

The handle `{ crumb: { text: "some crumb text", capitalize: false } }` is nicely defined when using useMatches on `/app` (`Dashboard` page) for `/app`, as you can see from the image below:

[image]

But is undefined for the same `/app` route when using on `/app/some-project` (`ProjectGeneral` page) or **any other sub-page** for that matter:

[image]

Why does this happen? Shouldn't a handle from a route be defined on for that route on all sub-routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to realize here with your route organization is that the dashboard index route and the project route are sibling routes, e.g. one isn't a sub-route to the other. When on `"/app/some_project"` the `"/app"` index dashboard route isn't in the matched route tree. This is why you don't see its `handle` object returned.

From what I understand you want the `handle` to be coupled to the `"/app"` path segment, so logically it makes sense to declare the `handle` on that route object.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Login />
  },
  {
    path: "/app",
    handle: { // <-- handle with "/app" segment
      crumb: { text: "some crumb text", capitalize: false }
    },
    children: [
      {
        element: <RequireUserAuth />,
        children: [
          {
            element: <Layout />,
            children: [
              {
                index: true,
                element: <Dashboard />,
              },
              {
                path: ":project",
                element: <RequireProjectParameter />,
                children: [
                  {
                    index: true,
                    element: <ProjectGeneral />
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, that was the problem - needed to put the `handle` with the `/app` segment. Thanks!